# Using razor view engine for multilingual support html5 app

Tags: html, razor, multilingual

my keys and values for translating the web app (AngularJS) are located in DB
Is there a way for razor to get a request for sample_{culture}.html and manipulate the html containing translation keys to return a translated html?

Answer (score 0):

If you get your translation strings from the db instead of a resx file, you have to write your own resource provider:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx
This is not complicated and there are examples out there for a DB resource provider.

Once you have that, you can just localized the razer cshtml files. I don't think this works with normal html files though.

Comment: yes. but can razor catch any HTML from the client app and manipulate it to change the keys into values? any known sample?